# Openshift TLS configuration with API Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, aws-api-gateway, istio

I'm trying to deploy an angular app on Openshift with Istio as service mesh. Service yaml:

```
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angularapp
        service: angularapp
        version: v1
      name: angularapp
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: http
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
      selector:
        name: angularapp
```

So far everything works with http connection. To change to https connection, I configured the istio-ingressgateway route provided by the Red Hat Openshift Service Mesh operator installation to use passthrough

```
spec:
  host: istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.xxx.xx.xxxxxxx.opentlc.com
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
    termination: passthrough
```

and the istio's gateway resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: testnamespace-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        credentialName: "router-certs"
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

with the VirtualService pointing to 8080 port of angular app:

```
      route:
        - destination:
            host: angularapp
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Question: TLS configuration works and the exposed istio ingress gateway URL does have https connection. However, API Gateway issues this error when firing request to the mentioned istio URL:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

The weird thing is that it only happens half the time, the other half works, even after clearing browser cache after every run. Note that only the istio ingress gateway URL has https connection while the angular app as a standalone service only has http.

Sorry for the long-winded question and hope to get some help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the segment:

```
  port:
    targetPort: https
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
```

to istio ingress route configuration as the istio ingress service default configuration listens on portName: https

```
name: https  
port: 443  
protocol: TCP  
targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

> With passthrough termination, encrypted traffic is sent straight to
> the destination without the router providing TLS termination.
> Therefore no key or certificate is required.

Because your backend service is http, you should terminate SSL at edge using

```
termination: edge
```

Reference: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/networking/routes.html

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I've tried to switch the istio ingress gateway route to edge, and I'm not able to access the URL at all with the following error: {"message": "Network error communicating with endpoint"}